# Google Sheets: Can I drop the last entry of a range in a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I am using Google Sheets to calculate grades in my course. The lowest grade in each marking period only counts half as much as the others. In the first free cell after the grades, I enter:

```
=transpose(sort(transpose(C3:E3),1,False))
```

which puts the lowest grade last; then I can take the mean of all grades, both original and sorted, but ignoring the last column. Thus every grade but the lowest gets counted twice in the average. (This approach would allow me to give special treatment to the lowest *n* grades, if desired.)

Out of curiosity, can I alter the formula above so the result does not even contain the last (i.e. lowest) entry? It would be more elegant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(C3:E3), "order by Col1 asc", ), "offset 1", ))
```